# Interactive graph in Colab

Tags: python, graph, mouseevent, interactive

Does anyone know if there's a way to make a graph such that axes values are displayed on hover in Colab?

I found a couple answers along the lines of

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

f,a = plt.subplots()
x = [0,1,2,3]
y = [5,6,7,8]
a.plot(x,y)
pos = []
def onclick(event):
    pos.append([event.xdata,event.ydata])
f.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", 'hover')

plt.show()
```

but they don't seem to work in Colab unfortunately

Comment: I just sniped your code in to a python3 colab running in Chrome and it seems to plot fine.

Comment: it shows the coordinates on mouse hover?

Answer (score 4):

Try out the following bunch of code and modify it as per your function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.close()


ax.set_xlim(( 0, 2))
ax.set_ylim((-2, 2))

line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return (line,)

# animation function. This is called sequentially  
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return (line,)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                             frames=100, interval=100, blit=True)

# Note: below is the part which makes it work on Colab
rc('animation', html='jshtml')
anim
```

Answer (score 1):

Nm, I figured it out.

```
import IPython
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot

def configure_plotly_browser_state():
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''
        <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script>
          requirejs.config({
            paths: {
              base: '/static/base',
              plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.5.1.min.js?noext',
            },
          });
        </script>
        '''))

configure_plotly_browser_state()
init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x= x_data,
    y= y_data,
    marker={'color': 'blue', 'symbol': 42, 'size': "10"},
    mode='lines+markers+text',
    name = 'Data1',
    hoverinfo = 'x+y'
)

trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x= x_data2,
    y= y_data2,
    marker={'color': 'red', 'symbol': 42, 'size': "10"},
    mode='lines+markers+text',
    name='Data2',
    hoverinfo = 'x+y'
)

layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=True,
    title='Interactive chart',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Title',
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=18,
            color='#7f7f7f'
        )
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Title',
        titlefont=dict(
            family='Courier New, monospace',
            size=18,
            color='#7f7f7f'
        )
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2], layout = layout)
iplot(fig)
```